# An English translation of Kyoji Saito's paper "Quasihomogene isolierte Singularitäten von Hyperflächen"

Tags: translation-request, mathematical-german

I want to understand the argument of the famous Saito's Theorem on the characterization of quasi-homogeneous isolated hypersurface  singularities. But the original paper is written in German, which makes it hard for me to read.

If anyone has an English translation of the paper *Quasihomogene isolierte Singularitäten von Hyperflächen*, please let me know. Thanks a lot!